Change formatting on all pages in a SharePoint
So we have a SharePoint where we are trying to change color on hyperlinks throughout the whole site. We've uploaded an alternative CSS in the look and feel > masterpage, however we can't seem to get it to apply pages and wiki pages.
Even if I put in style tag with formatting in edit source on a page, the preview shows the changes but when I save it, it reverts to default.
Any idea how to make these changes?
